# Return type of random in Haskell when used in a function

Tags: haskell, random, types

Given:

```
import System.Random

data Rarity = Common | Uncommon | Rare | Legendary
              deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Enum, Bounded)
```

I wanted to instance `Random`, so I started out with something like:

```
randomRarity :: (RandomGen g) => g -> (Rarity, g)
randomRarity g = case random g of
  (r,g') | r < 0.50 -> (Common, g')
         | r < 0.75 -> (Uncommon, g')
         | r < 0.88 -> (Rare, g')
         | otherwise -> (Legendary, g')
```

but this fails because even though it knows it needs a random `Ord` from all the comparisons, it can't tell that what I really want is a random `Float`. So I think I need to type the return value of `random g`, but I ran into a problem:

`(random g :: (Float, ???))`

Since it's a tuple, what do I declare as the second type? I tried something like `(random g :: (Float, RandomGen t))`, but `t` cannot be deduced and I don't know how to match it up with `g`'s type. I got it to work by using `StdGen` everywhere instead of `RandomGen g`, but then I couldn't instance `Random`, and it probably ought to work with any random `RandomGen`, anyway. And, to be honest, I don't even care WHAT it is, since I'm just passing it on, but it feels like I'm being forced to. I tried to figure out the right type by doing the following:

```
randomRarity g@(RandomGen t) = case (random g :: (Float, RandomGen t)) of
  ...
```

but that operates on *type constructors* (private ones, no less), not *types*, so I think that's a fundamentally wrong approach.

After reasoning about it, the thing that finally worked for me was the following:

```
randomRarity g = case random g of
    (r,g') | r' < 0.50 -> (Common, g')
           | r' < 0.75 -> (Uncommon, g')
           | r' < 0.88 -> (Rare, g')
           | otherwise -> (Legendary, g')
           where r' = r :: Float
```

which is reasonably concise, but it declares another variable that's located far away from the thing it is intended to affect, and it means you have to do a double-take when you see that `r'` and then go figure out what it is, then come back. Worst of all, it leaves my curiosity unsatisfied. So my question is:

Is there a way in this context to tell `random g` to generate a Float at the time I call it either by correctly declaring the second type in the tuple, or else by somehow inferring it from `g`. Or, failing that, is there a way to constrain the type of `r` without declaring another variable like `r'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in this case the simplest solution is to explicitly type one of the numbers you're comparing to. This forces the `(<)` operation to be specialized to `Float`, which in turn forces `r` to be `Float`:

```
randomRarity :: (RandomGen g) => g -> (Rarity, g)
randomRarity g = case random g of
  (r,g') | r < (0.50 :: Float) -> (Common, g')
         | r < 0.75            -> (Uncommon, g')
         | r < 0.88            -> (Rare, g')
         | otherwise           -> (Legendary, g')
```

---

Otherwise, this is a know problem in Haskell and the standard solution is to use [`asTypeOf :: a -> a -> a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3aasTypeOf). It's just a type-restricted version of `const`, which restricts the type. So in this case, if we can't know the exact type of `random g :: (Float, ???)`, we could import [`first`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v%3afirst) from `Control.Arrow` and map over the first element of the pair for example like this:

```
randomRarity g = case first (`asTypeOf` (0 :: Float)) $ random g of
    ...
```

In particular, the added expression is of type

```
first (`asTypeOf` (0 :: Float)) :: (Float, a) -> (Float, a)
```

It's not very concise, but it works and is localized to the one place `random g` is used.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using GHC, you can use `-XScopedTypeVariables` (or add `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` to the top of your file) with the code

```
randomRarity g = case random g of
      (r::Float,g') | r < 0.50 -> (Common, g')
                    | r < 0.75 -> (Uncommon, g')
                    | r < 0.88 -> (Rare, g')
                    | otherwise -> (Legendary, g')
```

Or if you want to use standard Haskell, you can use

```
randomRarity g = let (r,g') = random g
                 in case r :: Float of
                   r | r < 0.50 -> (Common, g')
                     | r < 0.75 -> (Uncommon, g')
                     | r < 0.88 -> (Rare, g')
                     | otherwise -> (Legendary, g')
```